# Pointing a subdomain to an existing page on its domain (webpage it exists on)

Tags: subdomain

How can I create a subdomain that points to a page on the same webpage?

Such as:
sub.mywebpage.com to:
mywebpage.com/foldera/folderb/pagename

Answer (score 0):

You will need a webserver which will redirect requests for sub.mywebpage.com to the other url. This cannot be done using DNS alone.